# How to Contribute on behalf of an individual instead of organisation for Member Dues?

Tags: contributions

Under Contribution Configurations,
I see  "Allow individuals to contribute and/or signup for membership on behalf of an organization?" checkbox is available by default,
 is there any way we can contribute on behalf of individual  for Member Dues without using family relationship type?

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by adding query parameter cid=0 in the url
So if the url is

```
/civicrm/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/Fcontribute/transact&reset=1&id=10
```

You need to add cid=0 to the url as shown below

```
/civicrm/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/Fcontribute/transact&cid=0&reset=1&id=10
```

Comment: Not sure this is what is required. adding cid=0 means you submit the form 'not as you'. that is not the same as saying 'let Mary pay for the Membership of John'